# Insert image from users computer

Tags: javascript, html, image, insert

Hi I would like to know how to insert image from user's computer to my webpage.
For example a lot of websites have "insert image" button to choose you profile picture.
Coluld you please give me some code on how to do that... :) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a way of obtaining a file from the user's computer.

```
<form action="profile_pic.asp">
  <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Then you could assign an ID to the image and to the user and match them, for when the user logs in.

Will

Answer (score 1):

That depends on which technology,you want to use?

If you are Ok with Javascript 
I recommend to use this JS tool,[Dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/)

The implementation is simple

Add this snippet to the head section of your HTML code

```
<script src="./path/to/dropzone.js"></script>
```

Add this to the body section

```
<form action="/file-upload"
  class="dropzone"
  id="my-awesome-dropzone"></form>
```

Add the below Code too,to manage the file after submission

`<input type="file" name="file" />`

To learn more about it,refer to the main website.

http://www.dropzonejs.com/